# Equivalent weight of metal

Tags: physical-chemistry

A metal oxide contains $60$% metal.The equivalent weight of metal is

(1) $12$

(2) $60$

(3) $40$

(4) $24$

I know that the equivalent weight of metal oxide = equivalent weight of metal + 8.But how can i arrive at the answer with this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent mass of a substance(element or compound) is defined as the number of parts by mass of the substance which combine or displace directly or indirectly $1.008$ parts by mass of hydrogen or $8$ parts by mass of oxygen or $35.5$ parts by mass of chlorine or $108$ parts by mass of silver.

The equivalent mass is a pure number.When a known mass if element is changed into oxide directly or indirectly , the mass of oxide is noted.

MASS OF OXYGEN= Mass of oxide-mass of element
Thus,

$ Eq. Mass = \frac { Mass of element * 8} {Mass of oxide} $

Here in this question you need ti assume the mass of oxide to be $100g$.
So, the mass of metal is $60$ and mass of oxygen is $40$.
Substituting these values in the above formula you get $\frac {60*8} {40}$$ = 12$.
Hence the ans is $12$.